# Create webservice to get SQL data

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, web-services

I created a web server to retrieve data from my sql database. For this case I wanted to retrieve all "Reds" from my table where there are Reds, Greens and yellows.

Here is an example of my PRODUCTS table:

[image]

So from this table I may have a query to get all the REDS from PRODUCT2, and my sql query would be:

`SELECT PRODUCT2 from PRODUCTS where Type = 'Stop';`

Here is my stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

And this query works but when I create my web service and datahelper I get the error that my input string was incorrect and that my value is a string instead of of an int (which it should be)

Here is my web service code:

```
 [WebMethod]
   public int GetRed(int Type)
   {
      return DataHelper.GetRed(Type);
   }
```

Datahelper Code:

```
public static int GetRed(int Type)
{
   int PRODUCT1 = 0;
   var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TestComp\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=Database; integrated security=true;");

var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select PRODUCT1 from PRODUCTS where Type = 'Stop'");

con.Open();

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(dr.Read())
{
   PRODUCT1 = (int)dr["PRODUCT1"];
}

dr.Close();
con.Close();

return PRODUCT1;

}
```

I tested the query in SQL Server and it works fine so not sure what I am doing wrong here when trying to retrieve those values. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting this exception? While converting the db value to int? or somewhere else?

Comment: Your sample query queries for `PRODUCT2` but in your code you're querying for `PRODUCT1`. Are their datatypes different?

Comment: In the code above, you fail to tell the `SqlCommand` which `SqlConnection` it should use. This would lead to an exception with the message "Connection property has not been initialized." If your exception is coming from `GetRed`, I doubt it's coming from the version that you've posted above. If what's above *is* what you're executing, I don't think the error is coming from `GetRed`. Could you post a stack trace?

Comment: @AlexHumphrey, I attached my stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time wasted, with your stacktrace, I know the issue: You're not giving your command a connection.

You need this:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

Before

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: I changed the line where I parse PRODUCT1 and I still get the same error. Really confused as to why I am getting an error. Not really sure what value I need to put in to test the operation. if I put in PRODUCT1 I get the error so maybe I am wrong there.

Comment: @CSharpDev4Evr I have edited my answer, there's your problem.